# change font used for forest package

Tags: fonts, forest

I would like to be able to use the `forest` package to draw a diagram whose labels use the font "Linux Libertine O". I tried the following MWE but this ignores the font command. How can I make this work?

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [node
        [option 1] 
        [option 2]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh dear, turns out this was an extremely elementary question. The answer is: make sure to compile using `xelatex` rather than `pdflatex`!

I'll leave this question up rather than deleting it just in case someone is as confused as I am...

## Edit

As pointed out by @egreg in the comments, `pdflatex` doesn't actually produce any output. (I think the reason why I thought it did is that I was testing without the fontspec lines and then added them and ran latexmk in silent mode, then mistook the old pdf output for the result of a newly-run pdflatex.) In any case, `xelatex` is the way to go!

Comment: If you run pdflatex over the example in the question, you get no output at all.